# How to prevent data loss during the typecasting?

Tags: c

I was trying to read a bitstream from a file using fread as

```
fread(buff, buffSize, 1, fp);
```

. 
`buff is the buffer to which i am reading`
.
`buffSize is the size of buffer`, and `fp is the file pointer` from which i m reading.
After reading the data to a buffer,
I tried to typecast the buffer content to another struture varible. The Structure is of the form

```
typedef struct data
{
    char    id;
    short   value1;
    short   value2;
    ....
}data;
```

what I did was

```
data* var;
var = (data*)buff;
```

then I tried accessing the variables inside the structure, if the bitstream is like `00 b0 11   c1 00` if that is the case,
`var->id` should be `0x00`. and `var->value1` should be `0xb011` and `var->value2` should be `0xc100`

But what I am getting is

```
var->id = 0x00;
var->value1 = 0x11c1;
...
```

Why it is I am not getting as expected?
When I changed the first param type to short, value got in `var->id was 0x00b0`.
Is there anything like minimum access size is `2 Bytes` ?
How to resolve this problem ?
I just want to read only 1st Byte to `var->id` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because there's a [padding field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) just before `value1`, used for alignment. Instruct your compiler to "pack" the structure if you want to get rid of it. Each compiler has different syntax. For example, on `gcc` you would say:

```
struct  __attribute__ ((__packed__)) data {
    /* ... */
};
```